# Pointer troubles C++

Tags: c++, pointers, crash

I got the following code, which compiles perfectly but by executing the program, it just crashs and closes. I have no idea why.

```
main{
...
  MLdouble *u = NULL;
  _intersect(...,u,...); //u as MLdouble* type
... 
}

CurvatureCalc::_intersect(... MLdouble *u)
{
...
MLdouble test = 123.21
*u = test; //<---line where it crashes
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Probably is some easy thing i just oversee. Nowhere else u is used. What I tried already is different variations for example using u = &test, which obviously does not work either. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `u` is a null pointer. You dereference it. Bad things happen. What did you _expect_ to happen if you dereference a null pointer?

Comment: Also, _"compiles perfectly but by executing the program, it just crashs and closes"_, yes, welcome to computer programming. It's your job to make the code work properly, simply getting it to compile isn't enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are programming in C++, what you really should do is to pass the argument *by reference*:

```
CurvatureCalc::_intersect(... MLdouble &u, ...)  // Note use of & instead of *
{
    ...
    u = ...;  // No dereference
    ...
}
```

And call as "normal"

```
MLdouble u;  // Not a pointer
_intersect(..., u, ...);
```

---

Using pointers is the old C-way of *emulating* pass by reference, and it works not by passing a variable that is a pointer, but passing a pointer *to* the variable. Like this:

```
MLdouble u;  // Not a pointer
_intersect(..., &u, ...);  // Note use of address-of operator & here
```

What you are doing now is dereferencing a null pointer, and that's not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

> I got the following code, which compiles perfectly

It compiles because it's syntactically correct. Being syntactically correct does not imply that the program is *correct* entirely.

> but by executing the program, it just crashs

You have undefined behaviour in your code.

> What am I doing wrong?

You initialize a pointer to null:

```
MLdouble *u = NULL;
```

You pass the null pointer to a function:

```
_intersect(...,u,...); //u as MLdouble* type
```

You dereference the null pointer:

```
*u = test; //<---line where it crashes
```

Dereferencing a null pointer (or any pointer that doesn't point to a valid object) has undefined behaviour.

The solution is to use a pointer that does point to a valid object. Or, if you can modify `_intersect`, then change the parameter to be a reference so that you cannot accidentally pass a null value.

Answer (score -2):

Provide more code but at first look;

```
MLdouble *u = NULL; // u is nullptr,

*u = test; /* you pass pointer which doesnt point to any address yet
and write - unexpected behavior, even if you pass address of local variable to u aka u = &test
test will get destroyed when, 
and you pointer will point to "garbage"*/
```

so you have to use new operator then delete it or use smart pointers

```
MLdouble *u = new MLdouble(...);/// or auto u = new MLdouble(...);
delete u;
u = nullptr;
```

Comment: _"p will get destroyed when"_ huh? what is p? It doesn't answer the question if you make up a different problem and answer that instead.